# How to send request data in post request using zuul filter

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I am new to Zuul and I want to redirect to external url using zuul pre filter in spring boot application. I want to send request data to call external url (post method api in python).
When i try to send request data using below code, when i hit the url from postman,i get 405 The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

my code:

```
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
ctx.set(body);
```

when i hit the url like http://localhost:8080/customers/ passing request body in postman,it should redirect to external url (api method) by sending post data but i am getting getting 405 The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Could any one please help me in solving this issue? I want to send request data in zuul and call external api. Thank you

Comment: can you put a reproducer in github ?